# Remove .html extension from URL only in root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove the .html file extension from my URL's to make them look nicer. I've seen many examples of this and have tried them, but I'm struggling to find something that only works in the root, and doesn't apply to any subdirectories or subdomains.

Can I get any help with this?

Example:
example.org/test.html > example.org/test

example.org/food/xyz.html > example.org/food/xyz.html
login.example.org/something.html > login.example.org/something.html

Comment: Please ask the question in a more specific way. Currently the question is very broad and hard to answer. Why is your _specific_ issue? Why can't you simply modify one of the working examples and tailor it to your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, so I will concentrate on the main issue you mention:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.+\.html
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

Alternative approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

If this is limited to only a single host name (as your examples *might* suggest) depends on your setup. Such thing is easiest done if you place the rule in the *real* host configuration of your http server instead of using `.htaccess` style files. That is also why I append a general hint:

---

You should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using `.htaccess` style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

In the comment you wrote that you also want to *force* the shorter notation, so redirect users request a URL with such "file name extension" to the version without.

I don't really see any point in this, but it certainly is possible:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^.
RewriteRule ^. - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.+\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.+\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work pretty well, but not completely. For some reason, I can still visit via /about.html, even though the URL should rewrite to /about. Either way works, but I would like it to force the non-html version, if that makes sense..

Comment: @ShaneT Ok, added a version that should implement this too.

Comment: That one didn't work. I already have a bit of rewriting in place to force HTTPS and WWW.

Comment: @ShaneT Please try again, I made some modifications.

Comment: That code produces a 500 error. I've messed around with what was first suggested and have this:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]`

Which works, but again, I can't seem to force it to remove the extension.

You can see the example here: modernbusinessweb.com

Comment: If you receive an http status 500 then there has to be an entry in the http servers error log file. Could you please post that?

Comment: @ShaneT Ah, sorry, most likely you received an endless rewriting loop. I added a small modification again.

Comment: I'm still receiving the Too Many Redirects notice

Comment: @ShaneT Sorry, only returned now and saw your issue... Took a few minutes to tackle this down, I had to setup a test myself. The current version does work for me now without ending in an endless loop. I explicitly added lines to block such a loop.